# Merge records that meet a particular criteria - TSQL

Tags: t-sql, merge, union

SQL Server 2008

Hi

I have an issue where i have two of the same accounts which i would like to merge together, the list looks like below:

```
AcctID  AcctType  AcctSubType  Curr  TransType  Amount
1        CCY       SET          EUR   Opening    1000
1        CCY       SET          EUR   BUY        -100
1        CCY       SET          EUR   SEL        100
1        CCY       SET          EUR   Closing    1000
2        CCY       SET          EUR   Opening    2000
2        CCY       SET          EUR   SEL        100
2        CCY       SET          EUR   Closing    2100
3        CCY       INC          EUR   Opening    1000
3        CCY       INC          EUR   SEL        200
3        CCY       INC          EUR   BUY        -100
3        CCY       INC          EUR   Closing    1100
```

So basically i would like to merge it so it looks like this:

```
AcctID AcctType  AcctSubType  Curr  TransType  Amount
1      CCY       SET          EUR   Opening    3000
1      CCY       SET          EUR   BUY        -100
1      CCY       SET          EUR   SEL        100
2      CCY       SET          EUR   SEL        100
1      CCY       SET          EUR   Closing    3100
3      CCY       INC          EUR   Opening    1000
3      CCY       INC          EUR   SEL        200
3      CCY       INC          EUR   BUY        -100
3      CCY       INC          EUR   Closing    1100
```

However i can't think of the best way to code this in SQL in my stored proc.  I can only really think of a merge or a union, but i only want it to merge where there are two capital accounts, a capital account is signified by the 'CCY' AcctType and AcctSubType 'SET'.

A point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**:  Actual stored proc

```
CREATE TABLE #Workbook
(ID INT
,PortfolioID VARCHAR(20)
,PortfolioName VARCHAR(255)     
,InstrumentID VARCHAR(20)
,   IssueID                 VARCHAR(50)
,   CashAccountInstrumentID VARCHAR(20)
,   CashAccountName         VARCHAR(255)
,   CashAccountType         CHAR(3)
,   CashAccountSubType      CHAR(3)
,   TransactionClass        VARCHAR(10)
,   TransactionType         VARCHAR(20)
,   EffPostDate             DATETIME
,   TradeDate               DATETIME
,   SettleDate              DATETIME
,   CcySettle               VARCHAR(3)
,   DateItem                DATETIME
,   RunningTotalDate        DATETIME
,   Detail                  VARCHAR(300)
,   ProceedsLocal           FLOAT
,   Total                   FLOAT   
,   RunningTotal            FLOAT
,   ReconValue              FLOAT
,   ReconNotes              VARCHAR(50)
,   RecordType              VARCHAR(1)
,   Sequence                INT
,   RecordNum               INT
,   TransactionID           VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #Workbook
EXEC dbo.usp_Generic_ReconCashAccount_NEW '2010-10-01', '2010-10-    07', '', 'OOGENHF', 'SS','','','','','' 

DELETE FROM #Workbook
WHERE TransactionType = 'BBA'
OR (ProceedsLocal = 0 AND RecordType = 'T')
;;with needed as
(
select * from #Workbook w
WHERE w.CashAccountType = 'CCY'
AND w.CashAccountSubType = 'SET'
AND w.TransactionType In ('Opening','Closing')
AND w.CcySettle = w.CcySettle
)
select 
    min(ID)
,   PortfolioID
,   PortfolioName
,   InstrumentID
,   IssueID
,   min(CashAccountInstrumentID) as CashAccountInstrumentID
,   min(CashAccountName) as CashAccountName
,   CashAccountType
,   CashAccountSubType
,   TransactionClass
,   TransactionType
,   EffPostDate
,   TradeDate
,   SettleDate
,   CcySettle
,   DateItem
,   RunningTotalDate
,   Detail
,   sum(ProceedsLocal) as ProceedsLocal
,   sum(Total) as Total
,   sum(RunningTotal) as RunningTotal
,   sum(ReconValue) as ReconValue
,   ReconNotes
,   RecordType
,   Sequence
,   RecordNum
,   TransactionID
from needed
group by     ID,PortfolioID,PortfolioName,InstrumentID,IssueID,CashAccountInstrumentID,CashAccountName,CashAccountType,CashAccountSubType,TransactionClass,TransactionType,EffPostDate,TradeDate,SettleDate
,CcySettle, DateItem,RunningTotalDate,Detail,ProceedsLocal,Total,RunningTotal,ReconValue,ReconNotes,RecordType,Sequence,RecordNum,TransactionID

UNION ALL
(
select * from #Workbook
except
select * from needed
)
drop table #Workbook
```

Comment: You should not `GROUP BY` the columns that you use aggregates (i.e. `MIN` or `SUM`) on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
;with test (AcctID, AcctType, AcctSubType, Curr, TransType, Amount)
as
(
select 1, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'Opening', 1000
union all
select 1, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'BUY', -100
union all
select 1, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'SEL', 100
union all
select 1, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'Closing', 1000
union all
select 2, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'Opening', 2000
union all
select 2, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'SEL', 100
union all
select 2, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'Closing', 2100
union all
select 3, 'CCY', 'INC', 'EUR', 'Opening', 1000
union all
select 3, 'CCY', 'INC', 'EUR', 'SEL', 200
union all
select 3, 'CCY', 'INC', 'EUR', 'BUY', -100
union all
select 3, 'CCY', 'INC', 'EUR', 'Closing', 1100
union all
select 4, 'CCY', 'SET', 'SEK', 'Opening', 2000
union all
select 4, 'CCY', 'SET', 'SEK', 'SEL', 100
union all
select 4, 'CCY', 'SET', 'SEK', 'Closing', 2100
)
, needed as
(
select  *
from    test
where   AcctType = 'CCY'
    and AcctSubType = 'SET'
    and TransType in ('Opening','Closing')
)
select  min(AcctID) as AcctID
        ,AcctType
        ,AcctSubType
        ,Curr
        ,TransType
        ,sum(Amount) as Amount
from    needed
group by
        AcctType
        ,AcctSubType
        ,Curr
        ,TransType
union all
(   
    select  *
    from    test
    except
    select  * 
    from    needed
)
```

**EDIT**: Updated to support multiple currencys.

The only change is to wrap the final `SELECT - EXCEPT` in parantheses.

Comment: This has been a great help.  Am so close now, however in the needed table i need only the opening and closings where there is more than 1 AcctID for CCY and SET.  Any idea how this could be achieved?

Comment: This has been a great help. Am so close now, however in the needed table i need only the opening and closings where there is more than 1 AcctID for CCY and SET. Any idea how this could be achieved?

Comment: How do you know which ones are duplicates?

Comment: basically there can only be one capital account per currency.  So in the above table there are 2 for EUR as there are two AcctID's for 'CCY'& 'SET' for EUR.  In the above example their AcctID's are 1 and 2.

Comment: Hope this answers your question by the way, am happy to answer any more you may have

Comment: There you go. I think this is what you ment. :)

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't worked, i still get the 2nd capital account coming through rather than it being merged.  How can i send you a copy of my code?

Comment: I now get all the opening and closings i require following your change, but as i said above i still get the two capital accounts opening and closings rather than having these merged.

Comment: Can you provide more testdata? Specifying multiple currencys etc. And the desired result.

Comment: i've added my actual stored proc above in the edit, i don't know there is something a miss in my stored proc?  Am happy to supply some test data if required?

Comment: @user1249944: you should edit your own question to add more details, not the answer.

Comment: Sorry @PeterŠtibraný was unaware.  I've edited my question but cannot edit the answer.

Comment: @user1249944: actually you can edit the answer, but since you don't have enough reputation yet, someone has to approve your edit. Only after two people with enough reputation approve it, it is visible to everyone. In your case, it was better to edit your original question to update it with more details, than to edit this answer.